# Not able to select radio button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am new. I  want the relevant inputs to be activated based on the selection made. Here is my page's HTML

```
<body>

<form id="add_employer" method="post" action=".">
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='UAUPCMpOzGlCfPIZxAFkkhAqVVUxgoVw' />

  <p><label for="id_ind_or_company_0">Is employer an individual or company:</label> <ul id="id_ind_or_company"><li><label for="id_ind_or_company_0"><input id="id_ind_or_company_0" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="True" /> Individual</label></li>
<li><label for="id_ind_or_company_1"><input id="id_ind_or_company_1" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="False" /> Company</label></li></ul></p>
<p><label for="id_emp_family_name">Employer&#39;s Family Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_family_name" maxlength="30" name="emp_family_name" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_emp_first_name">Employer&#39;sFirst Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_first_name" maxlength="18" name="emp_first_name" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_emp_middle_name">Employer&#39;s Middle Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_middle_name" maxlength="18" name="emp_middle_name" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_emp_coname">Company Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_coname" maxlength="87" name="emp_coname" type="text" /></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
</body>
```

and here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("p:has(input)").hide()
            $("[value^='Add']").hide()
            //$( "#id_emp_family_name" ).click(function(){   });
        });


        $("label:contains('Individual')").click(function(){     
            $("p:has(input)").unhide()
        });
```

Please tell me how to find if one of the radio button has been clicked.The input fields should unhide on clicking but they are not unhiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>

<form id="add_employer" method="post" action=".">
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='UAUPCMpOzGlCfPIZxAFkkhAqVVUxgoVw' />

  <p><label for="id_ind_or_company_0">Is employer an individual or company:</label> <ul id="id_ind_or_company"><li><label for="id_ind_or_company_0"><input id="id_ind_or_company_0" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="True" /> Individual</label></li>
<li><label for="id_ind_or_company_1"><input id="id_ind_or_company_1" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="False" /> Company</label></li></ul></p>
<div id="divIndividual">
<p><label for="id_emp_family_name">Employer&#39;s Family Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_family_name" maxlength="30" name="emp_family_name" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_emp_first_name">Employer&#39;sFirst Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_first_name" maxlength="18" name="emp_first_name" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_emp_middle_name">Employer&#39;s Middle Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_middle_name" maxlength="18" name="emp_middle_name" type="text" /></p>
</div>
<div id="divCompany">
<p><label for="id_emp_coname">Company Name:</label> <input id="id_emp_coname" maxlength="87" name="emp_coname" type="text" /></p>
</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#divIndividual").hide();
            $("#divCompany").hide();
            $("[value^='Add']").hide();
            //$( "#id_emp_family_name" ).click(function(){   });
        });


        $("label:contains('Individual')").click(function(){     
            $("#divIndividual").show();
            $("#divCompany").hide();
            $("[value^='Add']").show();
        });

$("label:contains('Company')").click(function(){     
            $("#divIndividual").hide();
            $("#divCompany").show();
            $("[value^='Add']").show();
        });
```

Solution without updating HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $("p:has(input)").hide()
            $("[value^='Add']").hide()
            //$( "#id_emp_family_name" ).click(function(){   });
        });


        $("label:contains('Individual')").click(function(){
        $("p:has(input)").hide()
            $("#id_emp_family_name").closest("p").show();
            $("#id_emp_first_name").closest("p").show();
            $("#id_emp_middle_name").closest("p").show();
            $("[value^='Add']").show()

        });

$("label:contains('Company')").click(function(){     
$("p:has(input)").hide()
$("#id_emp_coname").closest("p").show();
$("[value^='Add']").show()

        });
```

Comment: My apologies. I have changed that but it still does not work.

Comment: changed the structure of your html abit.  here is a latest working example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/normangr7/4ta8aerm/3/

Comment: Many thanks for your input. But I can't change the html document as I am using Django forms and its being created by that. So I need a solution without changing the html.

Comment: not a problem, please find updated solution

https://jsfiddle.net/normangr7/4ta8aerm/4/

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?  Use the "Solution without updating HTML" code in my answer above.  The jsfiddle site seems to be working fine

Comment: So I put the later two event handlers inside the  $(document).ready() with the first function and it works now.    But it works in jsfiddle as such and if I put them inside $(document).ready() then jsfiddle stops working. Why is that so? Thanks a ton.

Comment: glad to hear, please mark as answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Strange. I am able to put the 2 functions inside the $(document).ready() function on JSFiddle and it works fine.  Maybe check the brackets and braces syntactically correct.

Comment: May be. I did not try hard there. Thanks to let me know.